# A Fourier-type integral of a piecewise function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

consider the integral :
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\lambda+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x^{1/n} \right \}}{n} \right)\frac{\cos(t\log x)}{x}dx$$
Where $\left\{ x\right\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, and $\lambda$ is a numerical constant given by:
$$\lambda=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 1}\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor  \right )\frac{dx}{x\log x}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}$$
 The integral in its current form is somewhat problematic. Thus, we integrate with respect to $t$, and we will assume that the interchange of the integral sings is allowed:
$$\int_{0}^{\tau}f(t)dt=\frac{-\lambda}{\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\tau\frac{\sin(\tau\log x)}{x\log x}+\frac{\cos(\tau\log x)}{x\log^{2} x}-\frac{1}{x\log^{2}x}\right)dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{  x^{1/n}\right \}}{n}\left(\tau\frac{\sin(\tau\log x)}{x\log x}+\frac{\cos(\tau\log x)}{x\log^{2} x}-\frac{1}{x\log^{2}x}\right)dx$$
It can be shown that the first integral vanishes. In the second integral, we introduce the variable $y=x^{1/n}$ such that it becomes:
$$-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau\frac{\sin(n\tau\log y)}{n\log y}+\frac{\cos(n\tau\log y)}{n^{2}\log^{2} y}-\frac{1}{n^{2}\log^{2}y} \right )\left \{ y \right \}\frac{dy}{y}$$
The first summation is the familiar Fourier expansion of the sawtooth function:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau\frac{\sin(n\tau\log y)}{n\log y}=\frac{\pi\tau}{\log y}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left \{  \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi}\right \} \right )$$
The second summation is recognized as the second periodic Bernoulli polynomial:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos( n\tau\log y)}{n^{2}\log^{2}y}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{\log^{2}y}B_{2}\left(\left \{ \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi} \right \} \right )$$ $$=\frac{\pi^{2}}{\log^{2}y}\left(\left \{ \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi} \right \} ^{2}-\left \{ \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi} \right \} +\frac{1}{6} \right )$$
And the third summation is equal to:
$$\frac{\zeta(2)}{\log^{2} y}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6\log^{2} y}$$
On collecting the terms, we get:
$$-\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tau}{\log y}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left \{  \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi}\right \} \right )+\frac{\pi}{\log^{2}y}\left(\left \{ \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi} \right \} ^{2}-\left \{ \frac{\tau\log y}{2\pi} \right \}  \right ) \right )\left \{ y \right \}\frac{dy}{y}$$
But this is very hideous. any ideas on how to evaluate the integral !?

Comment: For purely heuristic reasons, i believe it's evaluable.

Comment: Can you prove the integral converges? Can it be evaluated numerically?

Comment: Unfortunately, i wasn't able to prove that the integral exists. the summation of the fractional parts is very erratic, but after experimenting with it, it seems to be bounded for all $x$ ! i tried $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x^{1/n} \right \}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lfloor x^{1/n} \right \rfloor-1}{n}$$ in order to obtain a bound on the summation, but in vain !

Comment: the first summation above can be written as: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k+1)}{k!}\log^{k}(x)$$, and the second summation truncates at the integer nearest to $\log_{2}(x)$. i don't know if this could help !